# How do I import external python class into Vertex AI pipeline component?

Tags: google-cloud-vertex-ai, kubeflow-pipelines

I have a Vertex AI pipeline that uses a Python component.

```
@component(
    base_image="python:3.9",
    packages_to_install=[lots!],      
)

def my_comp(
parms
) -> str:
    from google.cloud import aiplatform
    aiplatform.init(project=project, location=location)
    bill=x.y()
```

and in x.py:

```
class y:
```

How do I use x.y in the component? I have tried importing into the component and the jupyter notebook that creates the whole pipeline but the component doesn't see it.
I have tried `from x import y` and also `import x`. x.py is in the same folder as the jupyter notebook.

Comment: Please specify actual file names, code, and error messages. For import issues, exact details often are important.

Comment: Ok thanks. I don't have access right now but as a general concept should what I'm doing be possible? Ie import to the component from a local.py?

Answer (score 0):

You can't just load a class from a local file.

Each component runs a standalone container (defined in the `@component` decorator) that does not have access to your local machine or anything outside itself.

If you need a library that you cannot just `pip install` and make use of the `packages_to_install` input, your best solution is probably to create a custom  container that includes it, and update the `base_image` keyword input.